# Write csv to excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have 13 csv files in a folder called data, and I want to export that csv's files in the numerical order (1.csv,2.csv ...13.csv) to a excel file having each sheet named (1,2,3,4,5...13). I tryed something like this:

```
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
import pandas

ordered_files = ['1.csv', '2.csv','3.csv','4.csv', '5.csv','6.csv','7.csv', '8.csv','9.csv','10.csv', '11.csv','12.csv','13.csv']

with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    for csv_file in ordered_files:
        pandas.read_csv(csv_file).to_excel(
                        ew, index = False, sheet_name=csv_file, encoding='utf-8')
```

And I have two problems with this:

1. As you see in my list, I can't import the files directly from my folder data, if I will try:

   ordered_files = ['data/1.csv']
   Wont found a valid csv.
2. If I use that list method, my sheet will be named 3.csv for example instead of just 3.

A side question, coming from csv I saw some columns that should be int number with the format as strings with a **'** in front.

Thank you so much for your time! I use python 3!

Comment: Are you using Windows or Unix? Path delimiter might be different, you may want to use os.path.join (`os.path.join("data","csv.1")`)

Comment: IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible

Answer (score 0):

If all that concerns you is removing the last four characters from the sheet names, just use `sheet_name=csv_file[:-4]` in your call to `to_excel`. The comment from @pazqo shows you how to generate the correct path to find the CSV files in your *data* directory.

More generally, suppose you wanted to process all the CSV files on a given path, there are several ways to do this. Here's one straightforward way.

```
import os
from glob import glob

def process(path, ew):
    os.chdir(path) # note this is a process-wide change
    for csv_file in glob('*.csv'):
        pandas.read_csv(csv_file).to_excel(ew,
                                           index = False,
                                           sheet_name=csv_file[:-4],
                                           encoding='utf-8')

with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    process("data", ew)
```

You might also consider generating the filenames using `glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))` but that would also require you to remove the leading path from the sheet names - possibly worthwhile to avoid the `os.chdir` call, which is a bit ugly.

Comment: I just want to add that "1.csv".rpartition(".")[0] is safer, since it only removes the extension. Even better, using `os.path.splitext("1.csv")[0]`

Comment: The csv sheet naming was solved, but how do I pass the os.path.join to my list? And also can't I take all the csv files that are in that folder? I will store only the 13 csv there so can I take them all at once?

Comment: @pazquo "safer" in the general sense, perhaps, and definitely more elegant. But with a specific extension of `".csv"` probably overkill when explaining to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

For importing files, the path is relative to the current working directory, if you use the absolute path it should work (such as "C:\data\1.csv" in windows, "/home/user/data/1.csv" in a Linux or Unix environment).

To remove the extension from the sheet name, list the file names without the .csv ( such as orderedlist = range(1:13) ), then:

```
pandas.read_csv(<directory> + str(csv_file) + '.csv').to_excel(
```

which might be:

```
pandas.read_csv(/home/user/data/ + str(csv_file) + '.csv').to_excel(
```

Alternatively, keep the list as is and change the sheet name to

```
sheet_name=csv_file.split('.')[0]
```

to only return the portion of csv_file prior to the '.' .

Comment: As a further point not really related to the question, but using ordered_list = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) will give you a list of the files in the current working directory (os.getcwd() will tell you which directory you are in).

Comment: Hello Tyler, you reply was helpful, I used ordered_list = os.listdir(path) where path is my data folder location, I ended up with this ['4.csv', '8.csv', '12.csv', '5.csv', '13.csv', '7.csv', '9.csv', '11.csv', '2.csv', '6.csv', '10.csv', '1.csv', '3.csv'] but this is unordored, can I order it somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, it wont work very well, but you can use ordered_files.sort() after the list is generated, however the output will be : ['1.csv', '10.csv', '11.csv', '12.csv', '13.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv', '4.csv', '5.csv', '6.csv', '7.csv', '8.csv', '9.csv'] because the filenames are being treated as strings, not numbered items.

Comment: I manage to sort it like this: a = sorted(ordered_list, key = lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))

Comment: Awesome. I always forget to use lambda. Excellent solution to the sorting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first question you could write relative path as follows:
`"data/1.csv"` or `'data//1.csv'`.

About your second point, your sheet is named like this because you are looping over your csv names, the values you are using for your sheet names are then: '1.csv',...
In my opinion you should have write this instead:

```
    from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
    import pandas

    ext = '.csv'
    n_files = 13

    with ExcelWriter('data//my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
        for i in range(1,n_files+1):
            pandas.read_csv('data//'+str(i)+ext)
                  .to_excel(ew, index = False, sheet_name=str(i), encoding='utf-8')
```

Because you have 13 files, named from 1 to 13, you should make a loop over this thanks to `range(1,n_files+1)`, range function generate a list of *n_files* integers starting from 1.

Hope it helps.